# rbenv version appears in list but won't install

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I'm trying to install Ruby 2.4.4 for one specific project.

When I run `rbenv install -l`, 2.4.4 appears in the list of available versions, but running `rbenv local 2.4.4` gives the error message "rbenv: version `2.4.4' not installed".

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: may help to do, rbenv install --verbose 2.4.4, and include output if its not obvious at that point.

Comment: @Justine Just to add a bit more detail, `rbenv install -l` lists all the versions that are _available to be installed_. But before you pick one to use with `rbenv local` you need to install that version using `rbenv install` in the way [Mike K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185310/mike-k) mentioned.

Comment: @mikej Ooh. That makes sense and worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> When I run rbenv install -l, 2.4.4 appears in the list of available versions

`rbenv install -l` lists all **available** ruby versions that can be installed. `rbenv versions` on the other hand lists all locally **installed** ruby versions.

> Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

You need to execute `rbenv install 2.4.4`